# How to combine sampled data from the same population?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, correlation, inference, approximate-inference

Let's say I have a friend and we both asked one group of people a different question. For example, I ask the group how old they are, and my friend asks them how much they weigh. If I meet up with my friend and we combine our data, is there a way to plot the age against the weight?

Lets say we asked the same 100 people and my results were:

Ages 0-18: 25
Ages 18-50: 50
Ages 50+: 25

And my friend's results were:
Under 100 lbs: 20
100-150 lbs: 30
150-200 lbs: 30
200 lbs+: 20

Is there a way we can determine how many people from ages 0-18 weigh under 100 lbs? Is there a way to approximate this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.

If you do not identify the subjects in order to attribute to each individual their age and weight, there is no way to obtain the correlation.

You may estimate the relation if you have a [correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence) from a previous study on the same (or on a similar) population. Even better if you have a [linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) equation or other regression equation.

In particular, if you have a linear regression equation from a previous study, for instance:
$$
w = 2 \times (a + 5)
$$
where $w$ is the weight in kilogram and $a$ is the age in years.
This is an approximate expression applicable for children between 1 and 5 years old, according to [Tinning and Acworth](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18021105). By the way, they have formulas up to 14 years old.

Comment: Can you further explain the correlation comment? If there was information available on other groups, I could use that correlation to put together a table? What would this correlation look like? Would that correlation be in the form of an equation and I could use that equation to plot my data?

Comment: @StatsNoob007: I've edited my post and added more information regarding linear regression.